# Inviting guests to a meeting via Adobe Connect 9 API

Tags: php, adobe-connect

I'm writing a small module in PHP to integrate Adobe Connect functionalities into Drupal 7.x. One of the features I was asked to implement is the possibility to add guests to a given protected meeting.

According to Adobe Connect API docs, the action was introduced in 9.3 as 'event-guest-invite' and it requires 2 parameters:

- sco-id: the SCO ID of the event;
- guestDetails: The guest first name, last and email separated by commas.

Here's an example:
https://myinstance.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=event-guest-invite&sco-id=123456789&guest-details=John,Doe,mymail@myprovider.com

According to the Adobe documentation I should get this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<results> 
    <status code="ok" /> 
</results>
```

But instead I get this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<results>
    <status code="invalid">
        <invalid field="sco-id" subcode="invalid-type"/>
    </status>
</results>
```

After looking at error using this:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/9.0/webservices/WS8d7bb3e8da6fb92f73b3823d121e63182fe-8000_SP1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a171ddf77-7ff3_SP1

I can't understand if it is a wrong documentation-related problem or it's something I'm doing wrong.

In addition, I've also checked and I'm sure that the permissions of the user I'm using to test the API are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events and vanilla meetings are distinct types in Connect. It appears the SCO ID you're referencing is for a vanilla meeting.

If you want to add participants to a regular meeting, use permissions-update with the principal ID of the participant to add:

```
https://myinstance.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=permissions-update 
    &principal-id=2006258745&acl-id=2007018414&permission-id=view
```

See also:
[Create Meetings API (section 7)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/9.0/webservices/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a171ddf77-7fca_SP1.html) and [Permissions-Update API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/9.0/webservices/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a171ddf77-7fcb_SP1.html)

Alternatively, if you just want restricted access to a meeting for participants that aren't registered users, you could allow guest access behind a passcode.
See [Set or Reset a Meeting Passcode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/connect/9.0/webservices/WSbb9f59127bea748a-4121d89612b610bec31-8000.html)